# Can I define a variable from gitlab-ci as a value in a variable in settings (or schedules)?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, var, schedule

Here's what I am trying to do.

in .gitlab-ci:

```
Check schedules pass:
  stage: check
  image: ${myimage}
  script:
    - MY_CI_VAR=aVeryLongVariable
    - echo "$MY_SCHEDULE_VAR"
```

In schedules:
[image]

Which is not working.

The reason I want to do this is for picking different variable (out of many in the job) on each schedule.

Comment: Are you using a self-hosted GitLab instance or gitlab.com ? -- If self-hsoted, what version of GitLab are you using? Variable expansion inside other variables was only introduced in a relatively recent version of GitLab/GitLab-Runner.

Comment: @sytech Yes, it is self hosted by the company I work in. 
`GitLab Enterprise Edition 13.12.12-ee`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to use [variables within other variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/index.html#use-variables-in-other-variables). This feature was released in [GitLab 14.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/09/22/gitlab-14-3-released/#use-variables-in-other-variables).

However, since you are using GitLab 13.x, this feature won't be available to you.

You may be able to get around this limitation by using a static value and altering your job script accordingly.

```yaml
myjob:
  before_script: |
    if [[ "$SCHEDULE_VAR" == "abc" ]]; then
        export FOO="$MY_CI_VAR"
    fi
  # ...
```

In versions of GitLab < 14.3 you can still make use of other variables within variables, but instead by using `$$` to preserve variables from evaluation.

Example from the docs:

```yaml
variables:
  FLAGS: '-al'
  LS_CMD: 'ls "$FLAGS" $$TMP_DIR'
script:
  - 'eval "$LS_CMD"'  # Executes 'ls -al $TMP_DIR'
```

Comment: Thanx, this is actually what I did. I used a script. But if gitlab was >14 then it would have worked out of the box the way I defined it in schedules? Is it correct?

Comment: @DimiDak I would think so. The docs don't call it out specifically, so I would imagine it is supported anywhere variables can be defined, unless otherwise stated. You can always give it a try on gitlab.com and see if it works there.